# How do I run part of my code until I break?

Tags: c++

I need help with my code I will put it all in if anyone can clean it up so it looks nice but I will then highlight what I need help with.

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        string ready;
        system("@echo off");
        system("cls");
        cout << "ready to play? (y/n to play.): " << endl;
        cin >> ready;
        if (ready != "y")
            do { 
                cout << "O.K. Goodbye!" << endl;
                return 0;
            } while (ready == "y");
            cout << "OK!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            int number = 0;
            int min = 1;
            int max = 125;
            int userinput;
            srand(time(0));
            number = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
            int guesses_left = 10;

                cout << "please try to guess a number between 1 and 125, you currently have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left" << endl;
                cin >> userinput;
                if (userinput > number){
                    cout << "Sorry your guess is too high, please guess again.";
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "you now have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left. Please choose again.";

                }
                else if (userinput < number){
                    cout << "Soory, your guess is too low, please guess again." << endl;
                    cout << "You now have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left. Please choose again.";

                }
                else if (userinput == number){
                    cout << "congrats you won :)... Here have a prize as you won with: " << guesses_left << " guesses left." << endl << "no but seriously WELL DONE!!! :D";
                    system("cd C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer");
                    system("iexplore https://media.property118.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Best-Property-Forum.jpg");
                    return 0;


            }


  return 0;  }
```

The bit I am struggling with is this

```
cout << "please try to guess a number between 1 and 125, you currently have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left" << endl;
            cin >> userinput;
            if (userinput > number){
                cout << "Sorry your guess is too high, please guess again.";
                cout << endl;
                cout << "you now have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left. Please choose again.";

            }
            else if (userinput < number){
                cout << "Soory, your guess is too low, please guess again." << endl;
                cout << "You now have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left. Please choose again.";

            }
            else if (userinput == number){
                cout << "congrats you won :)... Here have a prize as you won with: " << guesses_left << " guesses left." << endl << "no but seriously WELL DONE!!! :D";
                system("cd C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer");
                system("iexplore https://media.property118.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Best-Property-Forum.jpg");
                return 0;


        }
```

I am trying to loop this segment of code until I am bothered to add in you losing lives in the game. So if I get guess higher it should say it is higher and then loop back to give me another go. I have only started learning C++ yesterday and this is all mostly my code (some of it is  adapted from other peoples posts like the srand and number = rand thing are other peoples)

Comment: You have `} while (ready == "y");` in the wrong place. Put that after everthing that you need to loop.

Comment: where should I put this?

Comment: And move your initialization before the `do {`

Comment: I recommend you step through your program using  gdb. Then you can see yourself what is actually going on, and which variable contains which value...

Comment: Although you want to change the condition on the while.

Comment: drescherjm When I move everything before do{ it just gives me number is undefined

Comment: #include "stdafx.h" should be the first non comment line of your cpp file.

Comment: That was what I was getting at when I said ***And move your initialization before the do***

Comment: You should use loops. Try googling something like "C++ loop".

Comment: _"I will put it all in if anyone can clean it up so it looks nice"_: google _clang-format_ and nobody will ever need to clean your code up (despite the fact that nobody will do).

Answer (score 1):

I changed your "y/n" while loop to this :

```
cout << "ready to play? (y/n to play.): " << endl;
cin >> ready;
if (ready != "y")
{
   cout << "O.K. Goodbye!" << endl;
return 0;

}
 else
    cout << "OK!" << endl;
```

I am also giving you a while version if you want to force the user to press either 'y' or 'n' to go further :

```
        cout << "ready to play? (y/n to play.): " << endl;
        cin >> ready;
while ( ready != 'y' && ready != 'n')
{
cout << "Only answer with 'y' or 'n' "<< endl;
cin >> ready;
}
```

and the game loop where user guesses to this :

```
int guesses_left = 10;
cout << "please try to guess a number between 1 and 125, you currently have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left" << endl;
while (guesses_left != 0)
{
                cin >> userinput;
                if (userinput > number){
                    cout << "Sorry your guess is too high, please guess again.";
                    cout << endl;
            --guesses_left;
                    cout << "you now have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left. Please choose again.";

                }
                else if (userinput < number){
                    cout << "Soory, your guess is too low, please guess again." << endl;
            --guesses_left;
                    cout << "You now have: " << guesses_left << " guesses left. Please choose again.";

                }
                else if (userinput == number){
                    cout << "congrats you won :)... Here have a prize as you won with: " << guesses_left << " guesses left." << endl << "no but seriously WELL DONE!!! :D";
                    system("cd C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer");
                    system("iexplore https://media.property118.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Best-Property-Forum.jpg");
                    return 0;
            }
}
cout << "You have used up all your guesses." << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: DO I just put `while return 0;` or anything because it is expecting a while statement

Comment: What is expecting a while, also to which part of the code are you referring ?

Comment: the very very very last closing bracket in my main code

Comment: while return 0; is the same as a simple return 0; statement